# PySpark - Referencing a column named "name" in DataFrame

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to use PySpark to parse json data. Below is the script.

```
arrayData = [
    {"resource":
    {
        "id": "123456789",
        "name2": "test123"
     }
    }
 ]
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=arrayData)
df3 = df.select(df.resource.id, df.resource.name2)
df3.show()
```

The script works and the output is

```
+------------+---------------+
|resource[id]|resource[name2]|
+------------+---------------+
|   123456789|        test123|
+------------+---------------+
```

However, after I changed the text "name2" in the variable arrayData to "name", and referenced it in df3 as below,

```
df3 = df.select(df.resource.id, df.resource.name)
```

I got the following error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <bound method alias of Column<b'resource'>> of type <class 'method'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

I think the root cause might be that "name" is a reserved word. If so, how can I go around this?

Comment: use bracket notation,`df.resource['name']`

Comment: Suresh, Thank you. It works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the bracket notation which suresh mentioned. following is the code

```
df3 = df.select(df.resource.id, df.resource["name"])
df3.show()

+------------+--------------+
|resource[id]|resource[name]|
+------------+--------------+
|   123456789|       test123|
+------------+--------------+
```

if you want only id & name as column name in you dataframe you can use the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df4 = df.select(f.col("resource.id"), f.col("resource.name"))
df4.show()

+---------+-------+
|       id|   name|
+---------+-------+
|123456789|test123|
+---------+-------+
```